# When to use DFS and BFS

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

Here is graph searching problem In Facebook Hacker Cup. [Problem Link](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=1523599254559737&round=742632349177460) 

Problem Description:
MXN Matrix we have to find the minimum distance from source to target. There are lasers which changes direction and Also Fires laser in every step we take.

**Problem:**

I have used the same approach is described in the Editorial But i have used **DFS instead of BFS** and i am getting wrong answer to some of the case.
How the DFS is making a Difference Why DFS is not working on this while BFS work.
[Code LINK](http://ideone.com/1Y0Unj)

```
tHanks
```

[Editorial](https://www.facebook.com/notes/1043281905687710/)

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty simple. If you need to find the shortest path in an unweighted graph, you should use BFS. If you need a specific traversal order(like in topological sort), you should use DFS. If the order and the lenght of the path doesn't matter, you can use any of them. In this problem the shortest path is required, so BFS is an obvious choice(DFS doesn't work because it finds some path, not necessarily the shortest one).

Answer (score 2):

The particular reason why BFS is good for finding the shortest path is that BFS traverses nodes in such an order, that all the nodes that have the distance X to the source node are processed before all the nodes that have the distance X+1. This allows for a very simple and efficient way of finding the shortest path in the graph between two nodes: as you add a node to the queue, you know its distance to the source is 1 more that the node you are processing at the moment (it can't be smaller, otherwise it already would have been in the queue). If with the distance for each node you also remember which node you came to it from, you can easily restore the shortest path itself.

DFS traverses nodes in a different order, and hence can't be easily adjusted to find the shortest path.

Answer (score 1):

**BFS** -

Cases where you can use BFS-

1: To find minimum length path in an unweighted graph.

2: Level order traversal of a tree.

**DFS**:

Cases where you can use DFS-

1: To find any valid solution to a problem.

2: To check for existence of any path in a graph.

**NOTE** - Though they can be used in many other places.